# Custom Condition on Query

Tags: entities

I'm trying to add a custom condition in a query:

```
 $today = new DrupalDateTime();
 $today = $today->format("m-d");
 $ids = Drupal::entityQuery('user')
  ->condition('status', 1)
  ->condition("date_format('field_birthday','%m - %d')", $today, '=')
  ->execute();
```

Error:

> PHP message: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\QueryException:
>   "'date_format('field_birthday','%m-%d')

**Version Drupal 8.8.4**

What is the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try use [hook_query_TAG_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21database.api.php/function/hook_query_TAG_alter/8.2.x)

```
...
->addTag('my_module_birtday')

/**
 * Implements hook_query_TAG_alter().
 */
function my_module_query_my_module_birtday_alter(Drupal\Core\Database\Query\AlterableInterface $query) {
  $today = new DrupalDateTime();
  $today = $today->format("m-d");
  $query->addJoin('LEFT', 'user__field_birthday', 'field_birthday', 'field_birthday.entity_id = base_table.uid');
  $expression = "DATE_FORMAT(field_birthday.field_birthday_value,'%m-%d')";
  $args = [
    ':birthday'=>$today
  ];
  $query->where($expression . '=:birthday', $args);

}
```